# CallWindowProc crash on exit

Tags: c++, winapi

In order to hook a `wndproc`, I write a `wndprochook` and use `SetWindowLong`:

```
wndproc=(WNDPROC)GetWindowLong(hwnd_1,GWL_WNDPROC);
SetWindowLong(hwnd_1,GWL_WNDPROC,(LONG)wndprochook);
```

Now I have to do something in `wndproc` and at the end of the function, I call the original `wndproc`:

```
return wndproc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

It fails, but thank god I find `CallWindowProc`:

```
return CallWindowProc(wndproc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

Now it's working. So **Question1: Why do we have to use `CallWindowProc`? What's missing when simply calling `wndproc`?**

The hook is working good, but when I quit the program, it crashes. Of course, everything is done and the crash doesn't actually affect anything. But it's still bad to see a crash.
So **Question2: What may happened here and how to fix it?**

I'm sorry that I have no information about how the original program closes itself, since all that I do is just hooking the `wndproc` to capture some messages. So I'm just hoping someone experienced enough who have ever encountered similar situations before could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `CallWindowProc`:

> “If this value is obtained by calling the `GetWindowLong` function with the `nIndex` parameter set to `GWL_WNDPROC` or `DWL_DLGPROC`, it is actually either the address of a window or dialog box procedure, or **a special internal value meaningful only to `CallWindowProc`”**

You can't call the “special internal value“ except by doing the same as `CallWindowProc` does, and the easiest way to do that is to call `CalLWindowProc`…

By the way, have a look at `SetWindowSubclass`, it may ease things for you.

Comment: wow! that really explains...and could you come up with some answer of Question2?

Comment: Question2: Try to run it via a debugger, see where it breaks. In the worst case put everything in a try/catch.

Comment: @fritzone well, the problem is that I can't run the target program via a debugger... all that I did is to inject a dll when it begins.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Question 2:

From comments on another answer, it sounds like your subclass wndprochook is in a DLL that's injected into a process.  If that's the case, then during exit, your DLL may be unloaded while there are still messages pending for the window.  So the Window's class still points to your wndproc, but that code is unloaded, so it crashes.

The safest thing to do is probably to restore the original wndproc before you shut down.  For example, when your subclass sees WM_DESTROY or perhaps WM_NCDESTROY, you essentially reverse the steps you did when you subclassed the window: restore the original wndproc field in the window class, before doing your CallWindowProc with that message.  Your code will no longer be called, even if a few more messages trickle in for that window.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. It seems that the dll is unloaded after the target exe module. Besides, the windows should surely be unloaded before the instance. Am I right?

Comment: but I think your answer is still worthy, while maybe the dll could be detached sometimes and it should be good to keep everything as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

thx to Adrian McCarthy.

```
Private Function WndProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal MSG As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Select Case MSG
    Case WM_CUT, WM_PASTE, WM_CLEAR
        WndProc= 1
    Case WM_DESTROY, WM_NCDESTROY
        Call UnHookRKey(hWnd)
    Case Else
        WndProc= CallWindowProc(lngPrevWndProc, hWnd, MSG, wParam, lParam)
End Select
```

End Function